# Ruby .split() Regular Expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split the string `"[test| blah] [foo |bar][test|abc]"` into the following array:

```
[
    ["test","blah"]
    ["foo","bar"]
    ["test","abc"]
]
```

But I'm have trouble getting my regular expression right.

---

Ruby:

```
@test = '[test| blah] [foo |bar][test|abc]'.split(%r{\s*\]\s*\[\s*})
@test.each_with_index do |test, i|
  @test[i] = test.split(%r{\s*\|\s*})
end
```

I'm not quite there, this returns:

```
[
    [ "[test" , "blah" ]
    [ "foo" , "bar" ]
    [ "test" , "abc]" ]
]
```

---

What would be the correct regular expression to achieve this? It would be great if I could also account for new lines, say: `"[test| blah] \n [foo |bar]\n[test|abc]"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better to use `String#scan` for this:

```
> "[test| blah] \n [foo |bar]\n[test|abc]".scan(/\[(.*?)\s*\|\s*(.*?)\]/)
=> [["test", "blah"], ["foo", "bar"], ["test", "abc"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another sample:

```
'[test| blah] [foo |bar][test|abc]'.scan(/\w+/).each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [["test", "blah"], ["foo", "bar"], ["test", "abc"]]

"[test| blah] \n [foo |bar]\n[test|abc]".scan(/\w+/).each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [["test", "blah"], ["foo", "bar"], ["test", "abc"]]
```